# Browser infinite redirect

Tags: browser

Having just updated to Windows 10 Creators update (may not be relevant... I hadn't used my computer in several months) I am unable to view non-secure websites.

For example, if I view the BBC website using http://www.bbc.co.uk, I get the following appear in the browser. The URL is altered to [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk%2F%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk%2F%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk%2F%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk%2F%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252?org_url=http://www.bbc.co.uk%2F%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%2525252f%2525253forg%2525255furl%2525253dhttp%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fwww%2525252ebbc%2525252eco%2525252euk%3Forg%5Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ebbc%2Eco%2Euk%252f%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww%25252ebbc%25252eco%25252euk%2525252f%2525253forg%2525255furl%2525253dhttp%2525253a%2525252f%2525252fwww%2525252ebbc%2525252eco%2525252euk%253forg%255furl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww%252ebbc%252eco%252euk%25252f%25253forg%25255furl%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%252) and the following is displayed - [Browser message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdG4P.png).

However, if I view the BBC website using https://www.bbc.co.uk it loads fine.

The same can be said for any website using HTTP over HTTPS.

Something similar occurs in every browser, including Steams in-app browser. I have tried clearing browser caches.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Looks like a malicious browser extension or proxy.

Comment: Almost as soon as I asked the question I came across [this](https://community.bt.com/t5/Connected-Devices-Other/Constant-quot-redirect-loop-quot-error-messages-on-webpages/td-p/1534226). I shall answer for anyone else unfortunate enough to have to use BT equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this](https://community.bt.com/t5/Connected-Devices-Other/Constant-quot-redirect-loop-quot-error-messages-on-webpages/td-p/1534226) link. I've no idea what Smart Setup is, I assume its something that is supposed to be used the first time a router is used on a desktop machine - BT specific.

Turning off Smart Setup resolved this. To do this, follow these steps

1. Access your router via 192.168.1.254
2. Log into the router using admin password
3. Navigate to Advanced Settings
4. Click on Home Network tab
5. Click on Smart Setup tab
6. Click in the Enable Smart Setup "No" radio button
7. Click on Apply Changes